# can a sharedpref file packageName_preference.xml can be created under different dir than default directory

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

by default shareprefs are stored in as below in app data directory:
/data/data//shared_prefs/packagename_preferences.xml

how can we create sharedpref as below:
/data/data//shared_prefs/customDir/CustomName_preferences.xml
?

Comment: I don't think that is possible but how come that necessity??

Comment: we have 2 different processes which may use same sharedpref, so these share same package name, sharedpref will be overwritten/polluted, so was thinking to create separate dir based on pid under shared_prefs dir.

Comment: two sharedpreferences can be created wont that do?

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, Android doesn't provide a way to choose SharedPreferences directory, but you can do so by creating a custom database file with your own algorithm.

However, why would you want to create subfolders inside "shared_prefs" folder? The user won't notice it, it's only for you.

If you need to create a compact and more reliable database, you can better use SQL Database.

Comment: we have 2 different processes which may use same sharedpref, so these share same package name, sharedpref will be overwritten/polluted, so was thinking to create separate dir based on pid under shared_prefs dir

Comment: You can create two different SharedPreferences files with different names then, and depending on the pid, you can choose to edit the SharedPreferences you want easily.

Comment: for me shared_pref name has to be same, as that is used in a third party jar file which I can't modify, so thought of creating shred_pref in different dir but that doesn't look possible.